# ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview configure for ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm giving ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview 1 a spin and want to configure ninject with it.  Is the best way still to use [ninject.web.mvc extension](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc)? The sample Scott Gu [posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx) doesn't run.  It throws an "Error activating IControllerFactory" exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Scott Gu's code should read...

```
public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) 
{
    kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<SqlProductRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IControllerFactory>().To<NinjectControllerFactory>();
}
```

Where the NinjectControllerFactory is found in...

```
using Ninject.Web.Mvc;
```

So yes, you do still need the mvc extension for Ninject.

Perhaps there is a better/newer way to define the default controller factory in MVC 3, but that is how I did it.

There may also be some strange behavior coming from MvcServiceLocator as indicated in [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1584142/3999203.aspx#3999203).

Comment: With a Ninject implementation of IMvcServiceLocator, you don't technically need the NinjectControllerFactory.  The DefaultControllerFactory yields to the MvcServiceLocator for controller creation.  As long as Ninject has the necessary bindings, it's good to go.

Comment: To add to my above comment, currently the MvcServiceLocator requires a  binding for IControllerFactory.  If you don't have one (yes, even for DefaultControllerFactory), it will throw that error.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need "**Ninject.Web.Mvc**" to configure Ninject in MVC 3, as I've blogged in a post titled ["**Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Ninject**"](http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you're calling using the ninject kernel from your IDependencyResolver, that you're calling

```
_kernel.TryGet(serviceType)
```

The MVC framework will try to grab a different IControllerFactory if it is available, if you call "TryGet", it will return null and the framework will use the default Controller Factory instead.

If you're using unity instead, make sure you wrap the resolve in a try/catch block and return null in the catch. Although that will be kind of slow, because you don't really want to have a catch block be treated as a normal part of execution flow.